# Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'Class' object has no attribute 'Method'

Tags: python, function, class, object

I have a character class with this fullname method inside it.

```
def FullName(self):
            #Name + title
            return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

when i try and call it, i get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'Character' object has no attribute 'FullName'

I have created an instance of the character class called player

This is how i am calling it

```
        player.FullName(player)
```

This is the same for all the methods inside the character class. I'm not sure really what I'm doing wrong

```
class Charcter():
#Setup for charcters
def __init__(self, name, Cclass, damage, damageType, 
health, speed, abilty):
    #Player properties
    self.name = name
    self.Cclass = Cclass
    self.damage = damage
    self.damageType = damageType
    self.health = health
    self.speed = speed
    self.abilty = abilty

    #Invetory list
    Invetory = list()

    def FullName(self):
        #Name + title
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def ShowInventory(self):
        #Print every item in inventory
        for Item in Invetory:
            print(Item)

    def Death(self, Enemy):
        print("You have died fighting a " + Enemy.name)
        print("Game over")
        print("Press enter to load from a checkpoint")
        input("")
        #Load check point

    def Battle(self, Enemy):
        print(self.name + " Vs. " + Enemy.name)
```

Here is the full code for all the documents and classes, 
NewGame

```
import StartGame
import GameObjects
#from StartGame import Intro

def overview(userClass, gClasses):
    #convert to int, -1 because lists starts at 0
    userClass = int(userClass) - 1
    print("Class: " + gClasses[userClass][0])
    print("Damage: " + gClasses[userClass][1])
    print("Damage Type: " + gClasses[userClass][2])
    print("Health: " + gClasses[userClass][3])
    print("Speed: " + gClasses[userClass][4])
    print("Abilty: " + gClasses[userClass][5])

def newGame():
    #Class properties - Class name, damage, damageType, health, speed,  abilty
    #Male classes
    barbarian = ["Barbarian", "8", "Sword", "45", "16", "Rage"]
    goblin = ["Goblin", "11", "Dagger", "25", "32", "Pickpocket"]
    mage = ["Mage", "50", "Staff", "75", "16", "Splash"]
    maleClasses= [barbarian, goblin, mage]
    #Female classes
    valkayrie = ["Valkayrie", "94", "2h Axe", "750", "24", "Wirlwind"]
    archer = ["Archer", "7", "Bow", "20", "24", "Long shot"]
    witch = ["Witch", "100", "Staff", "300", "12", "Undead army"]
    femaleClasses = [valkayrie, archer, witch]


    #Users name
    print("What is your Characters name?")
    print("-------------------")
    userName = input("")

    genderIsValid = False
    #While gender isnt set, repeat
    while(genderIsValid == False):
        #Users gender
        print("What is your characters gender? [M/F]")
        print("-------------------")
        userGender = input("").upper()

        if userGender == "M" or userGender == "F":
            #Exit out of loop
            genderIsValid = True
        else:
            #Stay in loop
            print("Please enter a valid statement")
            genderIsValid = False

    #Users class
    print("And what type of warrior are you?")
    #if gender is male
    if userGender == 'M':
        validClass = False
        while validClass == False:
            print("1. A mighty barbarian")
            print("2. A sneaky goblin")
            print("3. A mystical mage")

            print("-------------------")
            userClass = input("")

            if userClass == "1":
                validClass = True

                #overview of class
                overview(userClass, maleClasses)


                validClassConfirm = False
                print("-------------------")
                print("Are you sure? [Y/N]")
                confirm = input("").upper()
                while validClassConfirm == False:
                    if confirm == "Y":
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #Create instance of the player
                        userClass = int(userClass) - 1
                        player = GameObjects.Character(userName, "Barbarian", "8", "Sword", "45", "16", "Rage")

                        #create class
                    elif confirm == "N":
                        validClass = False
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #back to selection
                    else:
                        print("Invalid option")

            elif userClass == "2":
                validClass = True

                #overview of class
                overview(userClass, maleClasses)

                validClassConfirm = False
                print("-------------------")
                print("Are you sure? [Y/N]")
                confirm = input("").upper()
                while validClassConfirm == False:
                    if confirm == "Y":
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #Create instance of the player
                        #Convert and minus 1 cuz list starts at 0
                        userClass = int(userClass) - 1
                        player = GameObjects.Character(userName, ["Goblin", "11", "Dagger", "25", "32", "Pickpocket"])
                        #create class
                    elif confirm == "N":
                        validClass = False
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #back to selection
                    else:
                        print("Invalid option")

            elif userClass == "3":
                validClass = True

                #overview of class
                overview(userClass, maleClasses)

                validClassConfirm = False
                print("-------------------")
                print("Are you sure? [Y/N]")
                confirm = input("").upper()
                while validClassConfirm == False:
                    if confirm == "Y":
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #Create instance of the player
                        userClass = int(userClass) - 1
                        player = GameObjects.Character(userName, "Mage", "50", "Staff", "75", "16", "Splash")
                        #create class
                    elif confirm == "N":
                        validClass = False
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #back to selection
                    else:
                        print("Invalid option")
            else:
                validClass = False
                print("Please enter a valid statment")

            #Give a detail overview with statues using lists

    #if gender is female
    elif userGender == 'F':
        print("1. A warrior valkayrie")
        print("2. A eagle-eyed archer")
        print("3. A fiendish witch")

        print("-------------------")
        userClass = input("")

        if userClass == "1":
                validClass = True

                #overview of class
                overview(userClass, femaleClasses)

                validClassConfirm = False
                print("-------------------")
                print("Are you sure? [Y/N]")
                confirm = input("").upper()
                while validClassConfirm == False:
                    if confirm == "Y":
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #Create instance of the player
                        player = GameObjects.Character(userName, "Valkayrie", "94", "2h Axe", "750", "24", "Wirlwind")
                        #create class
                    elif confirm == "N":
                        validClass = False
                        validClassConfirm = True
                        #back to selection
                    else:
                        print("Invalid option")


        elif userClass == "2":
            validClass = True

            #overview of class
            overview(userClass, femaleClasses)

            validClassConfirm = False
            print("-------------------")
            print("Are you sure? [Y/N]")
            confirm = input("").upper()
            while validClassConfirm == False:
                if confirm == "Y":
                    validClassConfirm = True
                    #Create instance of the player
                    #Convert and minus 1 cuz list starts at 0
                    userClass = int(userClass) - 1
                    player = GameObjects.Character(userName, "Archer", "7", "Bow", "20", "24", "Long shot")
                    #create class
                elif confirm == "N":
                    validClass = False
                    validClassConfirm = True
                    #back to selection
                else:
                    print("Invalid option")

        elif userClass == "3":
            validClass = True

            #overview of class
            overview(userClass, maleClasses)

            validClassConfirm = False
            print("-------------------")
            print("Are you sure? [Y/N]")
            confirm = input("").upper()
            while validClassConfirm == False:
                if confirm == "Y":
                    validClassConfirm = True
                    #Create instance of the player
                    player = GameObjects.Character(userName, "Witch", "100", "Staff", "300", "12", "Undead army")
                    #create class
                elif confirm == "N":
                    validClass = False
                    validClassConfirm = True
                    #back to selection
                else:
                    print("Invalid option")
        else:
            validClass = False
            print("Please enter a valid statment")

        #Give a detail overview with statues using lists
    else:
        print("Error, restart game")

    print("Press Enter to start the game")    
    print("-------------------")
    userClass = input("")

    print(player)
    StartGame.Intro(player)
    #new function
    #save data



newGame()
```

GameObjects:

```
class Character():
    #Setup for charcters
    def __init__(self, name, Cclass, damage, damageType, 
    health, speed, abilty):
        #Player properties
        self.name = name
        self.Cclass = Cclass
        self.damage = damage
        self.damageType = damageType
        self.health = health
        self.speed = speed
        self.abilty = abilty

        def FullName(self):
            #Name + title
            return '{}'.format(self.name)

        def ShowInventory(self):
            #Print every item in inventory
            for Item in Invetory:
                print(Item)

        def Death(self, Enemy):
            print("You have died fighting a " + Enemy.name)
            print("Game over")
            print("Press enter to load from a checkpoint")
            input("")
            #Load check point

        def Battle12(self, Enemy):
            print(self.name + " Vs. " + Enemy.name)



class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, Type, description, value):
        self.name = name
        self.Type = Type
        self.description = description
        self.value = value

        def printItem():
            print("Name: " + name)
            print("Type: " + Type)
            print("Description :" + description)
            print("Value: " + value)
```

StartGame:

```
import Enemies
import GameObjects

def Intro(player):
    print(player)
    #print("You better move fast " player.name + " your  village is under attack")
    print("You're village is being swarmed by plagued rats from the east \n and poisonous frogs from the west")
    print("")

    print("Which do you fight")
    print("1. Rats")
    print("2. Frogs")
    print("-------------------")
    choice = input("")

    #if rats
    if(choice == "1"):
        player.Battle12(Enemies.Rat())
        #Battle method           

    elif(choice == "2"):
        pass
        #battlemethod
    else:
        print("Invalid option")
```

Enemies:

```
class Enemy():
    #Enemies
    def __init__(self, name, damage, health, ability):
        #Enemies properties
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        #Later 
        self.ability = ability

        def isAlive(self):
            return self.health > 0

class Rat(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Rat", damage = 1, health = 2)

class Rat(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Frog", damage = 1, health = 2)
```

Comment: You need to call it with ```player.FullName()```. Self is implicitly given to the method when called.

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Charcter' object has no attribute 'FullName'.

Still gives me the same error

Comment: I have done that for you

Comment: I fixed the typo at the start of the Class definition but i also had to fix it where i create the instance of the object and I still get the error.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: player = Objects.Character(userName, "Archer", "8", "Bow", "30", "18", "Long shot")

Comment: This is the way im creating the instance.                         player = Objects.Character(userName, "Archer", "8", "bow", "30", "18", "Long shot")

Comment: I dont know if this means anything, but since changing the spelling of the class, the methods no longer come up through intellisense, almost like theres maybe a syntax error

Comment: Objects is the python file that the class is inside of

Comment: @FChris I have posted all the code for my game to see if you can pick out any other problems.

Comment: Looks like an indentation problem to me. Fix your indentation.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. From the first post I thought it was just a formatting error here on Stackoverflow, hence why it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found it. It was already in the first code you posted but I thought it was just a problem with the formatting here on Stackoverflow. It turns out your whole problem lies in your indentation. But lets take a step at a time.

So in your Character class, your method definitions are **inside** of your **init**.
This is why they are not part of the class and why your Players later do not have these attributes.

So it has to look like as follows:

```
class Character():
    # Setup for charcters
    def __init__(self, name, Cclass, damage, damageType,
             health, speed, abilty):
        # Player properties
        self.name = name
        self.Cclass = Cclass
        self.damage = damage
        self.damageType = damageType
        self.health = health
        self.speed = speed
        self.abilty = abilty
        self.Inventory = {}

    def FullName(self):
        # Name + title
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def ShowInventory(self):
        # Print every item in inventory
        for Item in self.Invetory: ## fixme
            print(Item)

    def Death(self, Enemy):
        print("You have died fighting a " + Enemy.name)
        print("Game over")
        print("Press enter to load from a checkpoint")
        input("")
        # Load check point

    def Battle12(self, Enemy):
        print(self.name + " Vs. " + Enemy.name)
```

Also notice that the Inventory is an attribute of the object, which gets initialized empty. Therefor you also have to access it with `self.Inventory` later in the ShowInventory Method.

The last thing I found was, that you created your Enemies wrongly. 
Frog should probably be a Frog class and not a second rat and you can call the init of your parent class with `super(CHILD, self).__init__(...)`.
So I changed your Enemy classes to look as follows:

```
class Rat(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rat, self).__init__("Rat", 1, 2, "")


class Frog(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frog, self).__init__("Frog", 1, 2, "")
```

I just omitted the keywords for brevity. Also if your parent init needs for values, you need to give it three values (you forgot ability, I just gave it an empty string for now).

That's all I found so far.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that you are doing this:

```
player = Player()
player.FullName(player)
```

And that’s causing the issue

While calling a function of the class there is no need to pass the object of the class.

`self` refers to the newly created object (itself), the instance whose method was called.

So calling:

```
full_name = player.FullName()
print "Full name : {}".format(full_name)
```

A suggestion: although you could use the `FullName` function, using a variable might just suffice.

Comment: Changing this still didn't fix it. If you read the comment above, this will help explain.